# Matlab: How to change focus between external and internal windows?

Tags: matlab, focus

I'm hoping this is an easy problem, but I haven't figured out the answer yet nor seen a good resource for this.  I'm running an experiment in Matlab, and at times we call to an external program.  After a certain amount of time, I want the participants to return to Matlab to take a survey, and then resume their task after they are done.  The problem is the external code is interactive, so a person could be typing or clicking and not see the survey open up, and after completing the survey I don't know how to automatically return them to their open program (although I know when they are done with their survey and automatically close the browser).  My toy code example would be:

```
    system('start \max notepad.exe')
    pause(60) %After x seconds a web page opens up in Matlab, how to ensure users see it?
    web('cnn.com') %I have code that will close this after they click on a certain link

    %After close browser, how to return to notepad where they left off?
```

Comment: Based on your description I assume that the window you're trying to redirect focus to is an external program (Notepad?). Are you not able to create a matlab figure window for text input? If you did that then you'd have the figure handle for that window and you could simply call figure(fig_handle) to redirect focus.

Comment: Yeah, we are actually trying to redirect focus to games.  One variation has a scrabble game, for instance, but others are more sophisticated games (e.g. Portal 2).  The problem is many of these games involves lots of key presses, so people miss it when our online survey pops up within matlab as focus returns to the external game.  Solving the problem with notepad should go a long way toward resolving my game problem.

Comment: Sorry, but im still not clear on what application window you're concerned with; are your games not coded in matlab? If you're essentially trying to use matlab as a wrapper that controls several other external programs, then you're probably not going to find an easy solution. It will likely require Java code either way. *Also, you'll have much better luck here if you explain more clearly exactly what you're trying to do, and why it's not working.

Comment: Okay.  As part of an experiment, we are using an eyetracker and various other physiological devices, which we coordinate in Matlab.  As part of our experiment, participants play games and then take surveys about those games after a few minutes. The games are not coded in Matlab, these are generally commercial games. We do not need to track all their responses to the games or anything like that.  What we do want to do is make sure the subject plays the game for X minutes, then takes the survey, then continues playing the games for X more minutes, then takes another survey, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two solutions may help you. Actually, it is a little complicate. Solution 1 use mex method control window of program by c code. Solution 2 is also complicate, just use MATLAB parallel toolbox. Hmm, I suggest your use solution 1.

---

### solution 1:

1. Create a cpp file, which controls your interactive program(i.e. window explorer here). code is below. copy and save the code as "ctrlWindow.cpp" at your MATLAB current folder.
2. compile ctrlWindow.cpp by compiler lcc:

   ```
   mex -setup % choose compiler: type this command at MATLAB command, then choose lcc complier on windows 32 system

   mex ctrlWindow.cpp % compile cpp: you would find ctrlWindow.mexw32 at current folder
   ```
3. run the mex file as m-file at MATLAB command:

   ctrlWindow('your_program_window_name',command);

i.e. window name of a folder "myfold" is myfold which is display on the top left of window, type command:

```
ctrlWindow('myfold',6);
```

this would minimize your folder window. I suggest you minimize your program window firstly, then maximize it, and participants would focus on your program again:

```
ctrlWindow('myfold',6);%minimize window
ctrlWindow('myfold',3);%maximize window and participants would focus on this window
```

command is here:

```
HIDE             0
SHOWNORMAL       1
NORMAL           1
SHOWMINIMIZED    2
SHOWMAXIMIZED    3
MAXIMIZE         3
SHOWNOACTIVATE   4
SHOW             5
MINIMIZE         6
SHOWMINNOACTIVE  7
SHOWNA           8
RESTORE          9
SHOWDEFAULT      10
FORCEMINIMIZE    11
MAX              11
```

//filename:ctrlWindow.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>

#include "mex.h"


void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
                  int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
    mxChar* winName; //name of window wanted to be found
    HWND hwnd; //handle of window
    int command; //command of control window
    // check number of input
    if(nrhs!=2)
        mexErrMsgTxt("input must be 2");
    // check class of input
    if (mxIsChar(prhs[0]))
        winName=mxGetChars(prhs[0]);//get name of window
    else
        mexErrMsgTxt("input 1 should be char -- name of window");
    if (mxIsDouble(prhs[1]))
    {
        command = (int) mxGetScalar(prhs[1]);//get command
        if(command<0 || command >11)//check command
            mexErrMsgTxt("No such command!!!");
    }
    else
        mexErrMsgTxt("input 2 should be a double");
    // find window
    hwnd = FindWindowW(NULL, (LPCWSTR)winName);
    if(NULL==hwnd)
    {
        MessageBoxW(NULL,(LPCWSTR) L"Can't find the window!!!",NULL,MB_OK);
        return;
    }
    ShowWindow(hwnd, command);//control the window
}
```

---

### Solution 2:

```
matlabpool open 2
```

open two matlab background, use first control your first program, use second one control your second program.

Comment: Solution 1 worked!  Thank you very much.  I was trying to look into PSSuspend and other windows processes instead, as I don't know (and thus didn't think of) C++.